# Knockout data-bind doesnot work on div element

Tags: knockout.js

I am following one of the tutorials of knockout The code works fine when i bind "foreach:lines" to "tbody" element. However, if i try binding "foreach" to a div element, it fails and throws an error.

working code

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:lines">           
  <tr>
<td width="25%">
            <select data-bind="options:$parent.products,value:product,optionsText:'shortDescription', optionsCaption:'Select a product ...'"></select>
    </td>
</tr>       
 </tbody>
```

However, if i wrap the tr with a div and move data-bind="foreach:lines" to the div element:

```
<tbody>
        <div data-bind="foreach:lines">           
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">
            <select data-bind="options:$parent.products,value:product,optionsText:'shortDescription', optionsCaption:'Select a product ...'"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>   
        </div>  
        </tbody>
```

With above code it throws error

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.Message: ReferenceError: $parent is  not defined;Bindings value:

Please let me know how is binding foreach to div different from tbody element

Comment: Knockout can only work on valid HTML. Your code is not valid HTML because use cannot put a `div` directly inside the `tbody` and the browsers are just removing the `div` element from the DOM that is why your inner bindings are not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` is not a valid child of a `table` or `tbody`, no browser will actually render it that way.  Chrome for instance will place that `div` before the `table` (and not within your table as you wanted).

```
<div data-bind="foreach: lines"></div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">
                <select data-bind="options:$parent.products,value:product,..."></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the context of the `select` element, `$parent` does not exist, hence the error.

Use *valid* html and knockout will work.

---

If you wanted to repeat those rows that way, you would have to use [containerless controls](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-4-using-foreach-without-a-container-element).  Comments can be placed almost anywhere, like here.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: lines -->
            <tr>
                <td width="25%">
                    <select data-bind="options:$parent.products,value:product,..."></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```