# Knockout using $data for component parameter within a foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'am starting to play with component but i'am struggling with this simple code.

When I put a breakpoint in the function `viewModel(params)`, the object `params.data` is my view model `viewModelHelloWorld` whereas I expected it to be an item of my array. What am I doing wrong ?

Html:

```
<body>
    Hello <span data-bind="text:name"></span>

    <table data-bind="foreach: arrays">
        <test-component params="data: $data"></test-component>
    </table>    

    <script type="text/html" id="line-items">
        <tr>
             <td data-bind="text: Key"></td>
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="presentation_knockout.js"></script>
</body>
```

javascript

```
(function() {
    function viewModelHelloWorld()
    {
        var self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable("foo");       
        self.arrays = [ {Key:"1"}, {Key:"2"} ];
    }

    function viewModel(params)
    {
        var self = this;
        self.Key = ko.observable(params.data.Key);
    }

    ko.components.register('test-component', {
        viewModel: viewModel,
        template: { element: 'line-items' }
    });

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModelHelloWorld());
}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't realize you were using the custom tag within a `<table>` element.  Apparently the browser is pushing it out since it's not a valid child.  The browser is effectively doing this:

```
<test-component params="data: $data"></test-component>
<table data-bind="foreach: arrays">
</table>
```

You would have to make sure you insert valid tags.  Might as well do this instead:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: arrays">
    <tr data-bind="component: { name: 'test-component', params: $data }"></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="line-items">
    <td data-bind="text: Key"></td>
</script>
```

With your component:

```
ko.components.register('test-component', {
    template: { element: 'line-items' },
    viewModel: function viewModel(params) {
        this.Key = ko.observable(params.Key);
    }
});
```

You'll still be able to add more columns for each row in your component.  Or better yet, make the entire table a component and build your view that way.  That would make the most sense.

We came across this before in a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685147/390278).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm little stumped by this one.  I tried your example and got the same results.  So there is definitely something different about parsing custom elements vs. parsing data bindings.

But there is a work around. If you use the [component binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html), the `$data` variable works as expected. e.g.

```
<table data-bind="foreach: arrays">
  <!-- ko component: { name: 'test-component', params: {data: $data} } -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

I have a feeling the implicit template inside the foreach is getting parsed before the foreach is applied, so it is getting parsed in the main view model context, ergo viewModel === $data, rather than getting parsed inside the foreach loop.  But that is just a theory.

Comment: I concur. I observe that the binding is being applied before the context change of the foreach binding takes effect.

Comment: I think the issue is the 'controlDescendantBindings' flag doesn't apply to custom elements.  The 'foreach' binding sets the 'controlDescendantBindings' to true to stop knockout from applying the bindings to the inner HTML.  But this doesn't seem to affect the custom element parsing.

Comment: Ah, I know what it is. This was something I addressed before. The short story, the browser is trying to do the right thing and pushing the custom element out of the table since it's not a valid element.